# How to get character offset of a dom element relative to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given the following HTML code:

```
<div>Some Text<span id="marker"></span>some more text</div>
```

I am looking for a way to get the character offset of the marker span relative to the div using JQuery or plain JavaScript.

e.g. in this example the offset would be 9 characters.

Comment: What is the problem? Is that not a valid question? I tried googling it, and only found offsets in the pixel sense ...

Comment: We expect to see code in questions that ask for code. But why do you want to do this? What's the real-world use case?

Answer (score 0):

```
var marker = document.getElementById('marker'),
    div = marker.parentNode;

console.log(div.innerHTML.indexOf('<span id="marker">')); // span offset (9)
console.log(marker.outerHTML.length); // span outer length (25)
```